# Java CARD Class compare method

Tags: java

```
int[] value = new int[5];
boolean result = true;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    value[i] = cards[i].getValue();
}
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = i;j < 5; j++) {
        if(value[i] == value[j + 1]) {
            result = false;
        }
    }
}
return result;
```

This code is essentially going to compare the values each card object has, and if two cards in the array have the same value return true. We have 5 cards in each hand and that is why the array length is 5. The `getValue` method returns an integer which is essentially the value of the card. I don't seem to know what I'm doing wrong to be getting errors on my method.

Comment: If you want people to help you, you should tell us what those errors are and what you expected instead.  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 3):

Your array access is incorrect when you use `j + 1`, that will be out of bounds when `j` is four (at the end of the length for `value`). And, I would prefer to use `value.length` instead of hardcoding. Something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < value.length; j++) {
        if (value[i] == value[j]) {
            result = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, as pointed out by Tom, in the comments; it is pointless to continue iteration when the `result` becomes `false`. You could simply return when it becomes `false` and avoid the `result` variable entirely. Like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < value.length; j++) {
        if (value[i] == value[j]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

**Another** option, in Java 8+, would be something like

```
return IntStream.of(value).allMatch(x -> value[0] == x);
```

Comment: And one should think about returning in the `if` branch, not just setting a certain result value. This avoids unnecessary time for traversing and checking the remaining array.